# Showing emoji in a UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, emoji

Not sure what I'm missing here, and searching hasn't helped me. I want to display emoji characters in a UILabel, and this isn't doing it:

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"AppleColorEmoji" size:16.0];
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0x1F431];
// ... etc.
```

Works fine with other non-letter unicode characters, e.g. chess pieces, but not with any emoji characters that I have tried.

Comment: Did you check that `label.font` is not `nil`?

Comment: Good point, I hadn't previously but I did now, and label.font = <UICFFont: 0xb9a5050> font-family: "Apple Color Emoji"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 16px

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are probably not using the correct encoding for your emoji characters. For instance in your example I think you are looking for something like this:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%C", 0xe04f];
```

Have a look at [this](http://arashnorouzi.wordpress.com/2011/08/31/adding-graphics-and-emoji-characters-to-apple-push-notifications/) table to get the encodings you need.

Comment: Interesting. That works, but isn't it the old Softbank proprietary encoding? I was expecting that the now-standard Unicode 6.1 encoding should (also?) work.

Comment: will apple reject the app if you use this unicode characters to display emojis?

Answer (score 77):

To use Emoji's just press <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> (⌃⌘Space). No need of using unicode for emoji.

Comment: Who the hell down voted? This is the best answer for using emoji through Storyboard.

Comment: I was tremendously surprised that such a thing is even possible.

Comment: Seriously, the best way to do this.

Comment: best answer, didn't know it is even possible.

Comment: This is so amazing. Saves a huge research and copy paste time. Kudos !!

Comment: Thank s for that short cut

Answer (score 17):

In xcode just go to the top bar and click EDIT > EMOJIS & SYMBOLS and an emoji box will pop up and you can literally add it to any text in the app, even works in the interface builder if you need to add it to the text of a uilabel there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Nice, this should be at the top because it's much more simpler than the accepted version.

Answer (score 7):

In Swift you can do:

```
label.text = ""
```

Be sure to include the quotes. Otherwise you'll be setting the text to whatever is in the variable.
The following would display as "cat":

```
let  = "cat"
label.text =
```

Answer (score 5):

The unicode 6.1 encodings work as well, but you would have to specify them like this:

```
label.text = @"\U0001F431";
```

Comment: From where I can get the list of unicodes of other icons?

Comment: @ShreeshGarg you can get unicode of other icon from http://apps.timwhitlock.info/emoji/tables/unicode