# Handling newer emoji characters in UILabel on older iOS versions

Tags: ios, nsstring, uilabel, tttattributedlabel

Is there a well defined way to handle newer emojis on older iOS versions in a UILabel? For example the taco, middle finger etc that were added in iOS 9.

Comment: Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/q/11619267/5060335

Comment: @UditS that isn't what I was asking. I was talking about how to handle newer emoji characters on older OS versions