# UILabel doesn't show some Emoji on device

Tags: ios, xcode, uilabel, emoji

When I use UILabel, I need to show some Emoji expression. As for , it has 2 different kind of [Unicode](http://punchdrunker.github.io/iOSEmoji/table_html/).`U+1F600`and `E415`, which is SB-Unicode. If I get the latter one and assign to UILabel's text, it won't show on my device. However it will show on simulator. How can I solve it?

Comment: Do you do something like `label.text = "\u{E415}"`? Cause that works for me on my device.

Comment: You may take a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11619267/showing-emoji-in-a-uilabel